# Java GUI Calculator: Values not constant?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm making a GUI calculator on Java. I've put in the actionlistener and buttons and stuff, and the buttons are being heard but whenever I press a number twice, double digits won't appear; only the second number will be shown. In my if statement, if an operation wasn't chosen (like + or -) then whatever number is pressed will be apart of the first number, like pressing 1 twice would make 11, not 1 and 1 separately - but that's what my calculator does anyway. If an operation is chosen then it will go to the second number. i haven't started my equal button yet but I want the numbers to form properly first. I cut down my code to two numbers so it's shorter on here. Thanks for anyone who helps!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

public class CalculatorY {
    public static  JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 5));
    public static JButton one, two, add;
    public static JTextField result;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("calc");
        result = new JTextField(null, 8);
        one = new JButton("1");
        two = new JButton("2");
        add = new JButton("+");
        add.addActionListener(new button());
        one.addActionListener(new button());
        two.addActionListener(new button());
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5, 5, 25));
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel.add(result);
        panel.add(one);
        panel.add(two);
        panel.add(add);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(200, 400);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
    }

    public static class button implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            String command = event.getActionCommand();
            String text = result.getText();
            int textLength = text.length();
            String letterValueOne = " ";
            String letterValueTwo = " ";
            String op = " ";

            String valueOne;
            switch (command) {
                case "1":
                        if (op == " ") {
                        if (letterValueOne == " ") {
                            letterValueOne = "1";   
                            System.out.println(letterValueOne);

                        } else {
                            letterValueOne = letterValueOne + 1;

                        }
                    } else {
                        if (letterValueOne != " " && letterValueTwo == " ") {
                            letterValueTwo = "1";
                        } else {
                            letterValueTwo = letterValueTwo + 1;     
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "2":
                    if (op == " ") {
                        if (letterValueOne == " ") {
                            letterValueOne = "2";   
                            System.out.println(letterValueOne);  
                        } else {
                            letterValueOne = letterValueOne + 2;

                        }
                    } else {
                        if (letterValueOne != " " && letterValueTwo == " ") {
                            letterValueTwo = "2";
                        } else {
                            letterValueTwo = letterValueTwo + 2;

                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "+":
                    System.out.println("+");
                    if (result == null) {
                        result = null;
                    } else if (letterValueOne != "") {
                        op = "+";
                        result.setText(letterValueOne + op);
                    } else if (letterValueOne != " " && letterValueTwo != " ") {
                        result.setText(letterValueOne + op + letterValueTwo);
                        op = "+";
                    }
                    break;
                }
                result.setText(letterValueOne + op + letterValueTwo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `op == " "` is not how `String` comparison works in Java, you should be using something like `" ".equals(op)` instead

Comment: So is the comparison I used issue here?

Comment: It's not going to help, in most cases, it will always be `false`

Comment: so how can I change the code so that the numbers can combine, like getting an 12 instead of changing the value from 1 to 2

Comment: Personally, I'd simplify your process.  Instead of relying on the text field to maintain the information you want, add each number/operand to a `List`, then simply append the new "character" to the text field.  When needed, simply iterate over the `List`, extracting each "character", test to see if it's a digit or operand and take appropriate action as required